# Add hover for an ::after pseudo element

Tags: css, sass

So I have the following piece of SCSS code:

```
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      a {
        color: $primary;
        &:hover {
          color: $secondary;
        }
      }
      padding: 10px;
      &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-3px);
      }
    }
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 1px;
      height: 90px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: $primary;
    }
  }
```

The `::after` adds a line on the front-end for me.

[image]

Is there a way that I can apply a background-color to the ::after hover effect? If I add in a hover to the `<ul>` element, it highlights the whole element which I don't want - I'd like to just highlight the line.

Comment: `&:hover:after { background-color: red }` if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @ChrisW. Would I eliminate the current `&:hover` or add it below it?

Comment: @ChrisW. that worked! I added `&:hover:after { background-color: $secondary; }` below `&:after`. If you'd like, submit a answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add hover effect for ul and change the ::after background color, Check the below code, your problem will be resolved.

```
ul
{
&:hover
      {
        &:after
        {
          background-color:$secondary;
        }
      }
}
```

**complete code**

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      a {
        color: $secondary;
        &:hover {
          color: red;
        }
      }
      padding: 10px;
      &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-3px);
      }
    }
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 1px;
      height: 90px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: $primary;
    }
  &:hover
  {
    &:after
    {
      background-color:$secondary;
    }
  }
  }
```